# Why is my Rails activerecord many-to-many through relationship not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

Three models Professor, Expertise & ExpertisesProfessor (the join table). I would like to use a has_many activerecord structure but when I call **Expertise.professors.all** I get an error

***NoMethodError (undefined method `professors' for Class:0x000000000a1ddda0)    ***

I want to be able to call Expertise.professors and Professor.expertise ???

I am comfortable with using HABTM instead of "has_many through" but for my project I prefer to use the the " has_many through " relationship so please if I could get solutions along those lines only if possible .

```
**professor.rb**
class Professor < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :expertise_professors
  has_many :expertises, through: :expertise_professors
end

**expertise.rb**
class Expertise < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :expertise_professors
  has_many :professors, through: :expertise_professors
end

**expertises_professor.rb**
class ExpertisesProfessor < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :expertise
  belongs_to :professor
end
```

**My Schema File**

```
# It's strongly recommended that you check this file into your version control system.

ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 2019_12_18_191008) do

  create_table "expertises", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
  end

  create_table "expertises_professors", id: false, force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "expertise_id", null: false
    t.integer "professor_id", null: false
  end

  create_table "professors", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
  end

end
```

Any ideas what I have missed ?

[image]

Comment: @MarekLipka I have added a screenshot of my rails console with the error I received. I am testing my associations in rails console for now

Comment: It seems 1) or you forgot to save the changes 2) or you need to do a `reload!` in the rails console 3) or you must do a spring stop 4) or you must check why there's `Expertise::ExpertiseProfessors` not just `ExpertiseProfessors`.

Comment: Also if the expertises_professors is a join table which has only foreign keys then why use `has_many through` and have the Rails stack initialize a model. It should be `has_and_belongs_to_many`. You table and model names conform with the naming conventions.

Comment: @SebastianPalma. Thanks for your response. Suggestions 1 to 3 I checked and during process and not were issue is. Suggestion 4 hopefully I can get ideas from community on the solution as I am not too sure were this is coming from

Comment: @AlokSwain . Thanks . I am trying to approach this as a has_many through build. I have tried to update my associations to achieve this. Any suggestions on additional changes I need to make that might be causing the issue i.e naming convention ?

Comment: I basically want to create an association between Professor , Expertise using the ExpertisesProfessor  (join table). I would like to use has_many through the join table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not call `Expertise.professors`. You first need to load the single record or object of the Expertise like

```
expertise = Expertise.first
```

And then you can get all professors

```
expertise.professiors.all
```

Same way you can get all expertises for specific professor.